# Create digital-virtual-downloadable WooCommerce products from the frontend using Gravity Forms?

Tags: plugins, post-meta, plugin-gravity-forms

A little background about my issue: I'm running WP + WooCommerce + Gravity Forms and want to enable users to create WC digital-virtual-downloadable products from the frontend using GF. Essentially, users upload audio files using GF's Custom Field values (File Uploads) with **mp3** as the *meta key* (the **file path/URL** to the uploaded file is the *meta value*).

Since WC stores digital products as post meta fields, as well, under the **_file_paths** meta key, I thought I could go that route, but it turns out that it's not as simple as that. The *meta value* for WC's _file_paths is actually stored as an array with an MD5 hash.

My questions is, how do I duplicate the **mp3** *meta value* under the WC's **_file_paths** *meta key* and store it as an array with that md5 hash. Alternatively, if there's another way to accomplish this, I'm totally open to that, as well (ie. store *meta value* as an array under **_file_paths** *meta key* and somehow throw in that hash).

Here's something that might help with the answer - http://docs.wedevs.com/woocommerce-downloadable-product/

Answer (score 1):

Without coding the whole thing yourself, this sounds like what the [Cred plugin](http://wp-types.com/home/cred/) was written to do. Using the Toolset suite is, of course, limiting compared to doing everything hands-on but the trade-offs in terms of deployment time are pretty massive.

If you want to get down with a lot of hand coding, there are tutorials on how to do what you are asking.

Yoast also [talked a bit about](http://yoast.com/gravity-forms-custom-post-types/) updating custom post types using Gravity a while back (without code).

Whatever avenue you chose, it's not going to be a 10 minute solution.

Comment: I looked into that, as well, before going with GF. I actually had this working using WPUF and the linked snippet, but somehow it no longer works with the latest release of WC. GF gives you a lot more granularity in what you can do, so I thought I'd ask around, hoping for that *10 minute* solution ;-) I'll probably just wait till WPUF resolves that issues and try to go that route instead. Thanks for the feedback!